# can't not install Distribute, zlib

Tags: zlib, distribute, python-3.2

At first, I only want to use install feedparser with python3.2, while it need Distribute. When I install Distribute with

```
python3.2 setup.py install
```

I got

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/zipfile.py", line 687, in __init__
"Compression requires the (missing) zlib module")
RuntimeError: Compression requires the (missing) zlib module
```

Then I downloaded [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) and installed it with

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.2
make
sudo make install
```

After the installation, and tried to install Distribute, I got the same error.

Answer (score 8):

Finally, I solved it by re-install python3.2 with zlib.

1 Of course, you need to install zlib first. and you can find zlib.h in /usr/include

2

```
./configure -with-zlib=/usr/include
make 
sudo make install
```

from http://www.1stbyte.com/2005/06/26/configure-and-compile-python-with-zlib/